# What is the best structure to find which AABB boxes in a dynamic set collide with an arbitrary AABB box?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, collision-detection

I have a set of dynamic AABB boxes whose positions and sizes are updated continuously. What is a structure I can use to get which AABB boxes of those are colliding with an arbitrary AABB box?

Comment: It is an axis aligned bounding box, that is, a spacial box whose normals are aligned with the X, Y, Z axis of the coordinate system. Checking collisions for those is usually easy and inexpensive.

Answer (score 1):

Use a dynamic AABB tree.  [Here's some source code + documentation](http://bulletphysics.org/Bullet/BulletFull/structbtDbvt.html) (cpp files are at the bottom of the page)